# Julia - @code_warntype issue with ProgressMeter

Tags: performance, for-loop, progress-bar, julia

Using this for loop with [`using ProgressMeter`](https://github.com/timholy/ProgressMeter.jl):

```
function test()
       @showprogress 1 "Computing..." for n in 3:5:20
           print()
       end
 end
```

I don't understand why `@code_warntype test()` returns at three lines a type warning and most importantly how to fix it:

```
 %18 = φ (#2 => %12, #3 => %14)::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64,Int64}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how `for`-loops work internally in Julia, there is nothing you need to worry about or fix here, see https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/interfaces/#man-interface-iteration-1.

In particular, `for`-loops call `iterate` on the object you iterate over, and return `nothing` if the iterator is done, or a tuple with `loopvariable, state`. For this particular case, `iterate` of a `StepRange{Int,Int}` you thus get back `Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int,Int}}` from the `iterate` call:

```
julia> @code_warntype iterate(3:5:20)
Body::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64,Int64}}
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you, before I select your answer, how can I know when there is nothing to worry and when I have to worry when code_warntype returns red types?

Comment: This union in particular shows as yellow, not red, meaning that its "probably not a bad thing". In particular "small unions" with singleton types is usually not a problem, e.g. `Union{Missing, X}` or `Union{Nothing, X}`. Other examples that return unions intentionally is the `find*` family. See also https://julialang.org/blog/2018/08/union-splitting

Answer (score 1):

You may take side of `while`-loop. They don't return small unions.
UPD: Doing so can be overworking. @code_native depicts no difference between implementations. Instead of outer loops, i'd focus on costly function calls to be type-stable.

```
    function f()
       for i=1:12
       end
    end
    function g()
        i=1
        while i<13
            i+=1
        end
    end
    @code_warntype f()

    Variables
    #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(f, false)
    @_2::Union{Nothing, Tuple{Int64,Int64}}
    i::Int64

    Body::Nothing
    1 ─ %1  = (1:12)::Core.Compiler.Const(1:12, false)
    │         (@_2 = Base.iterate(%1))
    │   %3  = (@_2::Core.Compiler.Const((1, 1), false) === 
    nothing)::Core.Compiler.Const(false, false)
    │   %4  = Base.not_int(%3)::Core.Compiler.Const(true, false)
    └──       goto #4 if not %4
    2 ┄ %6  = @_2::Tuple{Int64,Int64}::Tuple{Int64,Int64}
    │         (i = Core.getfield(%6, 1))
    │   %8  = Core.getfield(%6, 2)::Int64
    │         (@_2 = Base.iterate(%1, %8))
    │   %10 = (@_2 === nothing)::Bool
    │   %11 = Base.not_int(%10)::Bool
    └──       goto #4 if not %11
    3 ─       goto #2
    4 ┄       return

    @code_warntype g()

    Variables
    #self#::Core.Compiler.Const(g, false)
    i::Int64

    Body::Nothing
    1 ─      (i = 1)
    2 ┄ %2 = (i < 13)::Bool
    └──      goto #4 if not %2
    3 ─      (i = i + 1)
    └──      goto #2
    4 ─      return
```